# How to change gstreamer omxh264enc profile?

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to convert a webcam on a raspberry pi to x264, but keep running into an error about an " Unsupported profile constrained-baseline".

```
GST_DEBUG=3 /home/pi/gst-rtsp-server/examples/test-launch "( v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert !  omxh264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 )"
stream ready at rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test
0:00:03.043939441 10314 0x75c08350 WARN                 v4l2src gstv4l2src.c:692:gst_v4l2src_query:<v4l2src0> Can't give latency since framerate isn't fixated !
0:00:03.044207251 10314 0x7491de30 FIXME                default gstutils.c:3981:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<appsrc1:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
0:00:03.044211053 10314 0x7491de60 FIXME                default gstutils.c:3981:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<appsrc0:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
0:00:03.087901354 10314 0x7491de90 ERROR             omxh264enc gstomxh264enc.c:706:gst_omx_h264_enc_set_format:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> Unsupported profile constrained-baseline
0:00:03.087992083 10314 0x7491de90 ERROR            omxvideoenc gstomxvideoenc.c:2239:gst_omx_video_enc_set_format:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> Subclass failed to set the new format
0:00:03.088080988 10314 0x7491de90 WARN            videoencoder gstvideoencoder.c:678:gst_video_encoder_setcaps:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> rejected caps video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)5/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)I420, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
0:00:03.092800068 10314 0x7491de90 ERROR             omxh264enc gstomxh264enc.c:706:gst_omx_h264_enc_set_format:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> Unsupported profile constrained-baseline
0:00:03.092867411 10314 0x7491de90 ERROR            omxvideoenc gstomxvideoenc.c:2239:gst_omx_video_enc_set_format:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> Subclass failed to set the new format
0:00:03.092942775 10314 0x7491de90 WARN            videoencoder gstvideoencoder.c:678:gst_video_encoder_setcaps:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> rejected caps video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)5/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)I420, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
0:00:03.092983764 10314 0x7491de90 WARN                GST_PADS gstpad.c:4226:gst_pad_peer_query:<videoscale0:src> could not send sticky events
0:00:04.001816134 10314 0x7491de90 ERROR             omxh264enc gstomxh264enc.c:706:gst_omx_h264_enc_set_format:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> Unsupported profile constrained-baseline
0:00:04.001956914 10314 0x7491de90 ERROR            omxvideoenc gstomxvideoenc.c:2239:gst_omx_video_enc_set_format:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> Subclass failed to set the new format
0:00:04.002098111 10314 0x7491de90 WARN            videoencoder gstvideoencoder.c:678:gst_video_encoder_setcaps:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> rejected caps video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)5/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)I420, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
0:00:04.037642275 10314 0x7491de90 ERROR             omxh264enc gstomxh264enc.c:706:gst_omx_h264_enc_set_format:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> Unsupported profile constrained-baseline
0:00:04.037781284 10314 0x7491de90 ERROR            omxvideoenc gstomxvideoenc.c:2239:gst_omx_video_enc_set_format:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> Subclass failed to set the new format
0:00:04.037959303 10314 0x7491de90 WARN            videoencoder gstvideoencoder.c:678:gst_video_encoder_setcaps:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> rejected caps video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)5/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)I420, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
0:00:04.038154562 10314 0x7491de90 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3055:gst_base_src_loop:<v4l2src0> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:04.038222947 10314 0x7491de90 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3055:gst_base_src_loop:<v4l2src0> error: streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
0:00:04.038854870 10314 0x75c08350 WARN               rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:1834:default_handle_message: 0x75c4e120: got error Internal data stream error. (gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstBin:bin0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4))
0:00:04.039143357 10314  0x20b2490 WARN               rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:2127:wait_preroll: failed to preroll pipeline
0:00:04.039219346 10314  0x20b2490 WARN               rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:2384:gst_rtsp_media_prepare: failed to preroll pipeline
0:00:04.053306794 10314 0x7491de90 ERROR             omxh264enc gstomxh264enc.c:706:gst_omx_h264_enc_set_format:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> Unsupported profile constrained-baseline
0:00:04.053442678 10314 0x7491de90 ERROR            omxvideoenc gstomxvideoenc.c:2239:gst_omx_video_enc_set_format:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> Subclass failed to set the new format
0:00:04.053582781 10314 0x7491de90 WARN            videoencoder gstvideoencoder.c:678:gst_video_encoder_setcaps:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> rejected caps video/x-raw, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)5/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, format=(string)I420, interlace-mode=(string)progressive
0:00:04.079457589 10314  0x20b2490 ERROR             rtspclient rtsp-client.c:678:find_media: client 0x2010610: can't prepare media
0:00:04.081144660 10314  0x20b2490 ERROR             rtspclient rtsp-client.c:2210:handle_describe_request: client 0x2010610: no media
```

There isn't anything in the docs for omxh264enc about profiles that I can find:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 omxh264enc
Factory Details:
  Rank                     primary + 1 (257)
  Long-name                OpenMAX H.264 Video Encoder
  Klass                    Codec/Encoder/Video
  Description              Encode H.264 video streams
  Author                   Sebastian Dröge <sebastian.droege@collabora.co.uk>

Plugin Details:
  Name                     omx
  Description              GStreamer OpenMAX Plug-ins
  Filename                 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gstreamer-1.0/libgstomx.so
  Version                  1.14.4
  License                  LGPL
  Source module            gst-omx
  Source release date      2018-10-02
  Binary package           GStreamer OpenMAX Plug-ins source release
  Origin URL               Unknown package origin

GObject
 +----GInitiallyUnowned
       +----GstObject
             +----GstElement
                   +----GstVideoEncoder
                         +----GstOMXVideoEnc
                               +----GstOMXH264Enc
                                     +----GstOMXH264Enc-omxh264enc

Implemented Interfaces:
  GstPreset

Pad Templates:
  SRC template: 'src'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      video/x-h264
                  width: [ 16, 4096 ]
                 height: [ 16, 4096 ]

  SINK template: 'sink'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      video/x-raw
                  width: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
                 height: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
              framerate: [ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ]

Element has no clocking capabilities.
Element has no URI handling capabilities.

Pads:
  SINK: 'sink'
    Pad Template: 'sink'
  SRC: 'src'
    Pad Template: 'src'

Element Properties:
  name                : The name of the object
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: "omxh264enc-omxh264enc0"
  parent              : The parent of the object
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Object of type "GstObject"
  qos                 : Handle Quality-of-Service events from downstream
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: false
  control-rate        : Bitrate control method
                        flags: readable, writable, changeable only in NULL or READY state
                        Enum "GstOMXVideoEncControlRate" Default: -1, "default"
                           (0): disable          - Disable
                           (1): variable         - Variable
                           (2): constant         - Constant
                           (3): variable-skip-frames - Variable Skip Frames
                           (4): constant-skip-frames - Constant Skip Frames
                           (-1): default          - Component Default
  target-bitrate      : Target bitrate in bits per second (0xffffffff=component default)
                        flags: readable, writable, changeable in NULL, READY, PAUSED or PLAYING state
                        Unsigned Integer. Range: 0 - 4294967295 Default: 4294967295
  quant-i-frames      : Quantization parameter for I-frames (0xffffffff=component default)
                        flags: readable, writable, changeable only in NULL or READY state
                        Unsigned Integer. Range: 0 - 4294967295 Default: 4294967295
  quant-p-frames      : Quantization parameter for P-frames (0xffffffff=component default)
                        flags: readable, writable, changeable only in NULL or READY state
                        Unsigned Integer. Range: 0 - 4294967295 Default: 4294967295
  quant-b-frames      : Quantization parameter for B-frames (0xffffffff=component default)
                        flags: readable, writable, changeable only in NULL or READY state
                        Unsigned Integer. Range: 0 - 4294967295 Default: 4294967295
  inline-header       : Inline SPS/PPS header before IDR
                        flags: readable, writable, changeable only in NULL or READY state
                        Boolean. Default: true
  periodicity-idr     : Periodicity of IDR frames (0xffffffff=component default)
                        flags: readable, writable, changeable only in NULL or READY state
                        Unsigned Integer. Range: 0 - 4294967295 Default: 4294967295
  periodicty-idr      : Periodicity of IDR frames (0xffffffff=component default) DEPRECATED - only for backwards compat
                        flags: readable, writable, changeable only in NULL or READY state
                        Unsigned Integer. Range: 0 - 4294967295 Default: 4294967295
  interval-intraframes: Interval of coding Intra frames (0xffffffff=component default)
                        flags: readable, writable, changeable only in NULL or READY state
                        Unsigned Integer. Range: 0 - 4294967295 Default: 4294967295
  b-frames            : Number of B-frames between two consecutive I-frames (0xffffffff=component default)
                        flags: readable, writable, changeable only in NULL or READY state
                        Unsigned Integer. Range: 0 - 4294967295 Default: 4294967295
  entropy-mode        : Entropy mode for encoding process
                        flags: readable, writable, changeable only in NULL or READY state
                        Enum "GstOMXH264EncEntropyMode" Default: -1, "default"
                           (0): CAVLC            - CAVLC entropy mode
                           (1): CABAC            - CABAC entropy mode
                           (-1): default          - Component Default
  constrained-intra-prediction: If enabled, prediction only uses residual data and decoded samples from neighbouring coding blocks coded using intra prediction modes
                        flags: readable, writable, changeable only in NULL or READY state
                        Boolean. Default: false
  loop-filter-mode    : Enable or disable the deblocking filter (0xffffffff=component default)
                        flags: readable, writable, changeable only in NULL or READY state
                        Enum "GstOMXH264EncLoopFilter" Default: -1, "default"
                           (0): enable           - Enable deblocking filter
                           (1): disable          - Disable deblocking filter
                           (2): disable-slice-boundary - Disables deblocking filter on slice boundary
                           (-1): default          - Component Default
```

I am new to gstreamer so I could be reading this all wrong, would appreciate any ideas or feedback! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change that through the SRC cap, try e.g.:

```
v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert !  omxh264enc ! video/x-h264,profile=baseline ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0
```